# Custom operation denormalize entity relationships

Tags: api-platform.com

My Entity(MealSet) has a file association so I have created a custom operation to process the request. My custom operation(MealSetController::class) attempts to denormalize the entity and the returns it. However, because my entity has a relationship, the denormalization fails and throws an error `Nested documents for attribute \u0022mealSetIncludes\u0022 are not allowed. Use IRIs instead.`.

How would one denormalize an entity that has relationships from within a custom operation?

```
// MealSet entity

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\MealAudienceCategory;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\MealSetController;
use App\Repository\MealSetRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "put"={
 *            "method"="POST",
 *            "path" = "/meal-sets/{id}",
 *            "controller" = MealSetController::class,
 *            "deserialize" = false
 *     },
 *    collectionOperations = {
 *        "get",
 *        "post" = {
 *            "security"="is_granted('CREATE_MENUAUDIENCE')",
 *            "method"="POST",
 *            "controller" = MealSetController::class,
 *            "deserialize" = false,
 *        }
 *    }
 *)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MealSetRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields={"name", "mealAudienceCategory"},
 *  message="The Meal Set name {{ value }} is already in use."
 *)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class MealSet
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write",
     *    "mealaudiencecategory:read",
     *})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(
     *    min = 2,
     *    max = 45,
     *    minMessage = "Name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *    maxMessage = "Name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write",
     *    "mealaudiencecategory:read",
     *})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(
     *    min = 2,
     *    max = 255,
     *    minMessage = "Description must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *    maxMessage = "Description cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     * )
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write",
     *    "mealaudiencecategory:read",
     *})
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="boolean",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     */
    private $published;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write"
     *})
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="integer",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     */
    private $displayOrder;


    /**
     * @var MealAudienceCategory
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=MealAudienceCategory::class, inversedBy="mealSets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write"
     *})
     */
    private $mealAudienceCategory;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MealSetIncludes::class, mappedBy="mealSet", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write"
     *})
     */
    private $mealSetIncludes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MealSetGroup::class, mappedBy="mealSet", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Groups({
     *    "mealset:read",
     *    "mealset:write"
     *})
     */
    private $mealSetGroups;


    /**
    * @Groups({
    *   "menuaudience:read",
    *})
    */
    public $contentUrl;

    /**
    * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media_object", fileNameProperty="filePath")
    * @Groups({
    *   "menuaudience:write",
    *})
    */
    public $file = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $filePath;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private $updatedAt;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mealSetSection = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mealSetIncludes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mealSetGroups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());

    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublished(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->published;
    }

    public function setPublished(bool $published): self
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDisplayOrder(): ?int
    {
        return $this->displayOrder;
    }

    public function setDisplayOrder(int $displayOrder): self
    {
        $this->displayOrder = $displayOrder;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getMealAudienceCategory(): ?MealAudienceCategory
    {
        return $this->mealAudienceCategory;
    }

    public function setMealAudienceCategory(?MealAudienceCategory $mealAudienceCategory): self
    {
        $this->mealAudienceCategory = $mealAudienceCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MealSetIncludes[]
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    public function getMealSetIncludes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->mealSetIncludes;
    }

    public function addMealSetInclude(MealSetIncludes $mealSetInclude): self
    {
        if (!$this->mealSetIncludes->contains($mealSetInclude)) {
            $this->mealSetIncludes[] = $mealSetInclude;
            $mealSetInclude->setMealSet($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMealSetInclude(MealSetIncludes $mealSetInclude): self
    {
        if ($this->mealSetIncludes->contains($mealSetInclude)) {
            $this->mealSetIncludes->removeElement($mealSetInclude);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($mealSetInclude->getMealSet() === $this) {
                $mealSetInclude->setMealSet(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MealSetGroup[]
     */
    public function getMealSetGroups(): Collection
    {
        return $this->mealSetGroups;
    }

    public function addMealSetGroup(MealSetGroup $mealSetGroup): self
    {
        if (!$this->mealSetGroups->contains($mealSetGroup)) {
            $this->mealSetGroups[] = $mealSetGroup;
            $mealSetGroup->setMealSet($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMealSetGroup(MealSetGroup $mealSetGroup): self
    {
        if ($this->mealSetGroups->removeElement($mealSetGroup)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($mealSetGroup->getMealSet() === $this) {
                $mealSetGroup->setMealSet(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFilePath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->filePath;
    }

    public function getContentUrl(): ?string {
      return $this->contentUrl;
    }

    public function setFilePath($filePath): self
    {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
        return $this;
    }
}


class MealSetController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke($slug = '', RequestStack $requestStack, MealSetRepository $em): MealSet
    {

        /*
          Determine if they are trying to edit an entity or create an entity.
          If edit, find the entity and use that object.
        */
        if($slug) {
          $obj = $em->findOneBySlug($slug);
          if(!$obj)
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Cannot find MealSet where SLUG ='.$slug);
        } else {
          $obj = new MealSet();
        }
        $serializer = $this->get("serializer");
        $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $data = array_filter($request->request->all(), function($x) { return ($x) ? true : false; }); //Grab the post data and filter out any empty strings.

        $extractors = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
        (new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractors))->denormalize($data, MenuAudience::class, 'json', [
          AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $obj,
          AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES => true,
          ObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true
        ]);

        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if($uploadedFile)
          $obj->setFile($uploadedFile);

        return $obj;
    }
}
```